# Android Get Application's 'Home' Data Directory

Tags: android, android-context, home-directory

A simple question, relating to the default 'home' directory when an app writes to the internal memory. By default, any files created are placed by the OS (2.2) in:

```
/data/data/your.package/files
```

When reading in files, the same default is used, when keeping in proper context via `openFileInput()`, `openFileOutput()`.  But if I need to check file existence, for instance, using the File class, I need to specify the whole path in the constructor.

I see there are `Environment.getDataDirectory()` (returns `/data`), `Environment.getRootDirectory()` (returns `/system`), etc, but nothing related to getting the app's 'home' directory.

It's not a huge deal, but I'd rather not hard-code the full path into my App for File to use (say the package name changes, say the path changes in a future OS release) if there is some way to reference the app's 'home' directory programmatically.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527764/get-application-directory

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Of course, never fails.  Found the solution about a minute after posting the above question... solution for those that may have had the same issue:

```
ContextWrapper.getFilesDir()
```

Found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29).

Comment: This returns `/data/data/<homeAppDir>/files`, but how to get path with out this "files"?

Comment: @Prizoff Use Context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir, as per [Kevin's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12792520/80425)

Comment: are you searching for this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527764/get-application-directory

Comment: The right way is: context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()

Comment: Quote: "Of course, never fails" is not completely true. They fixed a number of race conditions in Android 4.4 ...(see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8886)

Comment: @Paul Mennega how can i find all pacakges and its cache size ?

Comment: This is returning "/data/user/0/<homeAppDir>/files" on my Google Nexus 6, which is the wrong folder.

Comment: @MooingDuck It is because of the multi-user feature. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48393/what-kind-of-data-is-stored-in-data-user-directory

Comment: applicationContext.filesDir.path.dropLast(5)

Comment: @Prizoff I believe you are looking for getFilesDir().getParentFile(). This returns the parent directory f your application's internal storage. Inside this directory you have got all other directories likes files or caches.

Answer (score 44):

You can try `Context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir`
if you want the package's persistent data folder.

`getFilesDir()` returns a subroot of this.

Comment: This is returning "/data/user/0/<homeAppDir>" on my Google Nexus 6, which is the wrong folder.

Answer (score 18):

To get the path of file in application package;

```
ContextWrapper c = new ContextWrapper(this);
Toast.makeText(this, c.getFilesDir().getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```