# Android - autoupdate problem

Tags: android, auto-update

I use this code for saving app.apk from URL:

```
            Context ctx;
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

            FileOutputStream output = ctx.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("myApp.apk", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

than I save it from input to file by:

```
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
```

And after downloading, which is successfuly finished now I want to prompt installation  - I think I should use FileInputStream, but I don't know exactly how.

After downloading, I have code:

```
        Intent install=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(xxx - AND HERE I AM STUCK), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        ctx.startActivity(install);
```

I have tried `ctx.getApplicationContext().openFileInput("myApp.apk")`, but Uri.fromFile needs file and I am giving it openFileInput. Do you know how to solve it?

Thx

**Edit:** anyobody knows some some solution?

Comment: Can't you directly pass the myApp.apk path ?

Comment: how exdactly do you mean that?

Comment: If your file path is /sdcard/myApp.apk, then use Uri.fromFile( "file://sdcard/myApp.apk".

Comment: There is a problem with permission when accessing path where is stored myApp.apk by openFileOutput, thats why I need to have solution by openFileInput

Answer (score 0):

From: [Android Get Application's 'Home' Data Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739374/android-get-applications-home-data-directory)

Use getFilesDir() to return the absolute path to where openFileInput saved the file.  Then pass this to your File() constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
intent.setDataAndType( Uri.parse("file://" +
    context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() +
    "/" + update_file), ANDROID_PACKAGE);
```

and it works.