# Get Application Directory

Tags: android, directory

Does someone know how do I get the path of my application directory? (e.g. `/data/data/my.app.lication/`)

Currently I'm using this method: `myActivity.getFilesDir().getParent();` but it seems to me like a workaround when there's a simpler solution. Also, the side-effect is the creation of the `files` directory, which is un-needed.

*Clarification:* First - Thanks for the repliers. I try to understand if there's already exists method that does it, not for another work-around.

Comment: @MByD: Out of curiosity, what specifically are you trying to do? You should have no need for that directory. For example, if you want to work with the database directory, use `getDatabasePath()`. Or, if you want your own directory independent of anything else, use `getDir()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I have a shared object which is not under my control that creates several folders under my package folder, and I need to access them. I just wonder why isn't the base folder available by some method.

Comment: @MyByD: Tell whoever wrote that shared object to have their head examined.

Comment: @CommonsWare - What's so wrong about that? Also, My parents called me MByD for a reason, please don't call me MyByD `;)`

Comment: @MByD: Sorry about the name typo. With regard to the shared object, if they are expecting you to manipulate those files directly, at minimum they need to be giving you methods or something to get those directories, rather than you having to hack your own solution. Conversely, if they are *not* expecting you to manipulate those files directly, then they need some API to let you do what needs doing through their code. If what you're trying to do is well outside the shared object's scope, then you perhaps should not be trying to access the files.

Comment: It's a very very common thing when you use the NDK

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
String s = getPackageName();
PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo(s, 0);
s = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;
```

If eclipse worries about an uncaught `NameNotFoundException`, you can use:

```
PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
String s = getPackageName();
try {
    PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo(s, 0);
    s = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.w("yourtag", "Error Package name not found ", e);
}
```

Comment: although I use different solution, I found yours really "clean"

Comment: This gets you the APK path, `sourceDir` is an unfortunate misnaming. `dataDir` should be what you're looking for.

Comment: It returns the directory of the application, which is what the question asked for. Try reading the question properly before you vote people down.

Comment: I tried this implementation and eclipse told me there is an uncaught exception: Unhandled exception type PackageManager.NameNotFoundException

Comment: See my answer below which is a simple one liner.

Comment: is there any situation that PackageManager not exist in android app ?

Answer (score 118):

There is a simpler way to get the application data directory with min API 4+.  From any Context (e.g. Activity, Application):

```
getApplicationInfo().dataDir
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationInfo()

Comment: Warning : This may return `/data/user/...` on some devices.

Comment: Docs explicitly say not to use this.

Answer (score 25):

Just use this in your code

```
 context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir
```

Comment: Works great on Android 5.1, thanks! Nice and simple.

Comment: Is this the same as calling `android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` ?

Answer (score 21):

I got this

```
String appPath = App.getApp().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

[from here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/ba481797221e28aa?pli=1):

Comment: getFilesDir returns a subdir of dataDir

Comment: Please take time to read the question you are answering.  The getFilesDir() mechanism was already proposed and rejected as undesirable in the text of the question itself.  Additionally, as pointed out by njzk2 it does not return the desired result unless you take its parent directory, as done in the question.

Answer (score 10):

For current Android application package:

```
public String getDataDir(Context context) throws Exception {
    return context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).applicationInfo.dataDir;
}
```

For any package:

```
public String getAnyDataDir(Context context, String packageName) throws Exception {
    return context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).applicationInfo.dataDir;
}
```

Comment: can i find that a class is inside a package or not ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to get access to a file, try the `openFileOutput()` and `openFileInput()` methods as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).  They automatically open input/output streams to the specified file in internal memory.  This allows you to bypass the directory and `File` objects altogether which is a pretty clean solution.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I'm just trying to understand if there is a function that returns my application dir path, I'm using it a lot and my current solution looks pretty ugly to me.

Comment: @MByd, ah.  I gotcha, sorry it wasn't what you were looking for!

Comment: @MByD: When you say "I'm using it a lot", what do you mean? You do it in a lot of places in your code???

Comment: @MisterSquank - Yes. It seems like it's going to move to util class, but still...

Comment: As with the getFilesDir() approaches, this will not access the desired path but rather a subdirectory within it.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @jared-burrows' solution. For any package, but passing Context as parameter...

```
public static String getDataDir(Context context) throws Exception {
    return context.getPackageManager()
            .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0)
            .applicationInfo.dataDir;
}
```