# Access specified package directory

Tags: android, file, root, file-permissions

so im having problem with accessing root app data directory
my example dir:
/data/app/com.android.chrome-jAB96abq4RXcFrKebL0BUQ==

i want to get into /data/app/com.android.chrome without extension name to get list folder
tried /data/app/* com.android.chrome */ but got null

and here's my code

```
String path = "/data/app/*com.android.chrome*";
File file = new File(path);
String[] dir = file.list();
for(int i=0;i<dir.length;i++) {
Toast.makeText(this, "File: "+dir[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

and before that i've done changing the permission to 777 and using * com.android.chrome * goes well but my code above return null when try to listing directory

```
try {
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c chmod 777 /data");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c chmod 777 /data/app");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c chmod 777 /data/app/*com.android.chrome*")
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

tried without * package * and still got null
sry the stars doesnt have whitespace...got to whitespace because the texteditor recognize as text format

thanks before

Comment: So i must include com.android.chrome-jAB96abq4RXcFrKebL0BUQ== into path?

Comment: or is there another way to get a list of folders in com.android.chrome? because im sure each device has different -extension :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work, because `java.io.File` can not handle wildcards.
You have to specify the exact path.

As `/data` is not readable for regular users Java code will never be able to list a directory in this directory (a wildcard requires directory listing).

Get the app info via [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager) and the [`dataDir` from the `ApplicationInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo#dataDir) for the app you are interested in:

```
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.android.chrome", 0).applicationInfo.dataDir;
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12184033/150978)

Alternatively you can run a shell ls command with su/root that lists the `/data/data` directory and parse the result for the chrome app data directory.