# Can't find the recorded file using Media.startRecord

Tags: android, cordova, media, record

i am using the Media class to record from device mic, is sucessful recorded but i can't find the audio file(myrecording.amr) on my android device.

```
function recordAudio() {
    var src = "myrecording.amr";
    var mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();
    // Stop recording after 10 sec
    var recTime = 0;
    var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
        recTime = recTime + 1;
        setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");
        if (recTime >= 10) {
            clearInterval(recInterval);
            mediaRec.stopRecord();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    app.enabled("btnRecord", true);//IDE widget

}
// onSuccess Callback
//
function onSuccess() {
    app.alert("recordAudio():Audio Success");//IDE widget
    //app.setValue("labelmobile1", mediaRec.); IDE widget
}

// onError Callback 
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

// Set audio position
// 
function setAudioPosition(position) {
    app.setValue("label1", position);//IDE widget
}
```

Where i can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();     
File file = new File(filepath,<directoryName>);        
var src=file.getAbsolutePath()+""myrecording.amr"
```

Your file will be created inside `<directoryName>`

Answer (score 0):

My guess that it's created in your Android app home directory, since you are using relative path.

You can check here how to find your home directory:
[Android Get Application's 'Home' Data Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739374/android-get-applications-home-data-directory)

However, I agree with Mukund. It's much better to specify absolute path in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify a path then the Media.startRecord() method will default to putting your file at the location specified by Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). Check for it in /sdcard or /mnt/sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

you can find it in the sdcard and the path will be:

"/sdcard/myrecording.amr"