# How can I put .bak file inside my Android Application?

Tags: android, file

I have created an Android Application that should be used in different social environments (shops, airports, etc.)

Each of those wants their own `profile` (*their own background, button colours,etc.*). I recieved `.bak files` which hold this Profile`s, but I need to somehow include them inside the **Application Folder**, so that they get detected.

**I cannot find the Application Folder** on my Computer, when I connect my Android Device to it via USB cable (*so that I can copy / paste the .bak to that folder*). Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: you mean Android's private folder for your app?

Comment: I assume, yes. Or ANY way really, just to put those `bak`files inside my App, so when the App gets started it loads that Profile.

Comment: not sure what you trying to do, if you need the private dir where your app can load / store files, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739374/android-get-applications-home-data-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your app folder like this

```
getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()
```

For using permissions WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and/or READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are required.
And for first-time application launch is not better to put your .bak file with profiles to assets, and when apk will start first time copy to app-folder in background? Usually app-folder have path like "sdcard/Android/data/your_app_package_name/files" but if u did not write something to this folder, folder will not be created.

Comment: So with that, I can access a file that was pasted inside "MyProject" ?

Comment: Inside your project you can put this file into assets folder. When your app will start first time you can copy this file to app-folder (getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()) and after your can work with local copy of this file on device. If you want to get local copy of file on device you can find it in "sdcard/Android/data/yourproject_package_name".

Comment: Argh, the thing is, I dont have an SD card on the tablet... Any other way to do this ?

Comment: So you can do the same way but just use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() instead of getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()

Comment: And this will automaticly give the path to the File that I copy / pasted inside my project ? I didnt put it in assets (the .bak file), should I put it there, so that my App see's it with the above code?

Comment: yes then you can get it from your code like context.getResources().getAssets() and pass to stream, for example something like this "new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("filename.txt")));" and get file from this stream

Comment: Done. Accepted your answer. Thanks!