# file.delete() returning true but the file is still there

Tags: java, android, file, apk

I'm following this code to delete an apk file before downloading another one and then installing it

```
String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.apkname) + ".apk";
destination += fileName;
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);

File file = new File(destination);
if (file.canRead()) {
    if (file.delete()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I'm finding the file, so I get to file.delete() and then I get the toast message, but when I check in downloads, the file is still there and I end up with multiple files with the same name, I can still use them with no issues, so it's like file.delete() did absolutely nothing.

For the record, I have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest AND I request it in runtime too since I'm using sdkversion 25.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried restarting your Android device and verified if the duplicate files exists?

Comment: @Divya I'm using emulator, actually.

Comment: add `try` and `exception` and check what is error?

Comment: @NitinPatel Nope, no error reported at all

Comment: @SantiagoCuartasArango Still try performing a restart.

Comment: Then add condition that whether file is exist or not.

Comment: @NitinPatel If there was a need of `try` and `catch` construct. it would have halted the app execution but the OP is not saying that it is happening.

Comment: @NitinPatel I achieve that with file.canRead() because file.exists() wasn't working for me

Comment: @SantiagoCuartasArango Have you tried printing out the `destination` variable value?

Comment: @DivyaMamgai ok I restarted the emulator with no positive result, and destination prints "/storage/emulated/0/Download/perlajorgecuartasotorrino.apk"
Aditionally, I tried in my phone, and the same issue is happening

Comment: @SantiagoCuartasArango Please check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23761450/6249775). What Android version are you using in the emulator?

Comment: @DivyaMamgai android 6.0, both emulator and phone

Comment: @NitinPatel `File.delete()` doesn't throw exceptions. If there was a need for `try` and `catch`the code wouldn't have compiled, let alone executed.

Comment: @DivyaMamgai apparently that answer is a workaround that it's not working anymore

Comment: `delete()` should return `true`, and I think it actually deletes the file, or at least *some* file. Apparently, it's still there. Try to call `delete()` twice, the second call should return `false`. Second, try to upload this to a phone, for an emulator might spoof the deletion of the file, maybe by some configuration or something.

Comment: @SantiagoCuartasArango I knew it's a workaround but I just wanted you to realize that Android might not be allowing you to modify files that are not part of your App.

Comment: @MCEmperor doble call didn't work

Comment: @DivyaMamgai mmm so that's it? the files will accumulate from now on? that's really bad news since the people usually never checks download folder

Comment: check this link stackoverflow.com/questions/4943629/how-to-delete-a-whole-folder-and-content answer given by "teedyay"

Comment: @SantiagoCuartasArango No, you should try downloading your new APK to your own App's directory because according to that answer it is permitted to modify files their. Of course I'm assuming you want to download a updated version of your own APK but if that's not the case let me know.

Comment: @DivyaMamgai yeah, I want to download an updated version

Comment: @SantiagoCuartasArango Your code is working fine for `text` file in real device, I have checked. So, make sure check there is file.

Comment: @SantiagoCuartasArango Then I would not store it in the user's Download folder anyway. In fact I would prefer to not keep the APK once its installed. So you should try to download in Package-Specific location and delete it once installed to save user's space after all user is your first priority.

Comment: @SantiagoCuartasArango "Double call didn't work" — so what was the result? Did both calls return `true`?

Comment: @DivyaMamgai how can I do that? I only know how to download to the downloads folder

Comment: @MCEmperor yes..

Comment: @SantiagoCuartasArango Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739374/android-get-applications-home-data-directory). Modify your destination path accordingly. PS: [This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29) might be help full too.

Comment: @DivyaMamgai unfortunatelly I'm getting `java.lang.SecurityException: Unsupported path /data/user/0/<Package_name>/files/perlajorgecuartasotorrino.apk` in this line: `final long idDownload = downloadManager.enqueue(request);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution I have tested...

```
        String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
        String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.apkname) + ".apk";
        destination += fileName;

        try {
            File file = new File(destination);
            if (file.canRead()) {

                boolean mDeleleFile = file.delete();
                context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(destination))));
                if (mDeleleFile) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have reference from [How to delete a file from SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card)

Comment: The file is there but I'm still reaching the toast message, so `mDeleteFile` is true

Comment: I have tested this work for me. Once please check app permission go to manually.. by app info and check external storage permission

Comment: sorry for the delayed answer. Isn't the permission asked in runtime enough for that?
And your solution works on which android version?